# Creating a moving banner

Tags: html, banner

Currently for my webpage's banner, I'm using http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/ to have 4 images sliding. On the office's slower computers the coin slider seems to be very laggy.

My question is, would animating the 4 images into a single GIF file be better/faster? Are there better options to create a 4-image-moving banner?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a lightweight image gallery, I found some [here](http://blogupstairs.com/10-lightweight-image-gallery-slider-plugins/). The coin slider is lightweight 8KB but there are ones even lighter 2KB or so.

You could technically use a GIF but I think there are some mobile compatibility issues, you can also have better functionality with javascript/jQuery galleries.

As far as slow computers go there isn't much you can do about that, I wouldn't worry too much about it. Just do some extra research on how to minimise files and deliver a faster site.

Answer (score 0):

Gif is not a wise alternet for sliders..you could reduce the quality of your Images and compress them..or if you are using large images and resizing them in slider, you can re size them with any image alteration tool. This will reduce image size too.
And I hope you are not giving images path direct internet links, cause this will automatically increase the loading time.